# The result is random when group by some column that set collation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, collation

I have a query:

```
SELECT   DMT_INFORMATIONBIZ.Name COLLATE Japanese_CI_AI AS Name
FROM DMT_INFORMATIONBIZ
GROUP BY Name COLLATE Japanese_CI_AI
```

I run this query 2 times but the result of column [Name](this column use collate) is difference

1. Run 1st: [アウ] => full-size
2. Run 2nd: [ｱｳ] => half-size

Please help me:

1. why the result is diffence when I run same query.
2. How to fix the result(same result when run many times)

P/S: my English is not good, sorry for this inconvenience